# Chrome thinks I'm using a proxy

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

Chrome says "downloading proxy script" every time I try to load a page. It'll routinely give me an error `net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED` and fail to load the page.

I'm not using a proxy:

[image: Not using a proxy]
[image: Still not using a proxy]

If I go into Windows settings and turn off "automatically detect settings" Chrome behaves properly. But I don't want that off - I want Windows to configure itself while Chrome acknowledges I'm not on a proxy.

How can I see why Chrome thinks I'm on a proxy?

Comment: Have you tried to delete your Chrome user profile?  Are you connected to an enterprise network?

Comment: I am on a home network. I completely uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome. Would that have removed my profile?

Comment: No;  Deleting the profile directory would be the only way to do that.